# UIImageView within UITableViewCell not changing image

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, dispatch-queue

I'm a bit stuck. I have a custom `UIView` which contains a timer and an `UIImageView`, that timer fires at a constant interval and changes the image from an array of images. This custom view works fine and is performant when I embed it within any other `UIView`. It changes images at the prescribed speed and doesn't have any issues. It works as I'd like.

This exact same view however, when placed inside a `UITableVieCell` that looks like the below, renders only the first image and does not change. I have confirmed that the timer is firing, and the the image view is changing its image under the hood by printing the reference to the `UIImageView.image`. That is to say, that when embedded within a `UITableViewCell`, my custom `UIView` is firing its timer and the `UIImageView` within this custom view, thinks it is changing its image. This leads me to believe that this is a display issue and not a data setting issue.

As a result, here is what have tried:

1. I've tried wrapping it in `DispatchQueue.main.async{}`
2. Adding a delegate so that my `UIViewController` can call `tableView.reloadData()` when the timer is fired
3. Removing the setter of `multiImageView.images` on my `prepareForReuse`

**Custom Cell Below**

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

final internal class MultiImageCell: UITableViewCell {
    // MARK: - UI Elements
    public var multiImageView: MultiPartImageView = MultiPartImageView()

    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        //Setup Cell
        selectionStyle = .none

        //Setup Section Title View
        multiImageView.rotationSpeed = 0.3
        contentView.addSubview(multiImageView)

        //Setup Constraints
        setupConstraints()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        accessoryType = .none
        multiImageView.images = []
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        setupConstraints()
    }

    // MARK: - Functions
    private func setupConstraints() {
        //Setup Section View Constraints
        multiImageView.snp.remakeConstraints({ (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview().inset(16)
            make.width.height.equalTo(240)
        })
    }
}
```

**Setting Images on Cell**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Check for Cell
        guard let row = viewModel.row(at: indexPath) else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        // Setup Cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: row.cellReuseIdentifier,
                                                 for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = viewModel.title(for: row, indexPath: indexPath)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = row.detailText
        cell.accessoryView = row.accessoryView
        cell.accessoryType = row.accessoryType ?? .none
        cell.imageView?.image = row.image

        switch RowStyle(rawValue: row.cellReuseIdentifier) {
        case .multiImageCell:
            guard let multiImageCell: MultiImageCell = cell as? MultiImageCell else {
                return cell
            }
            guard let multiImageRow: MultiImageRow = row as? MultiImageRow else {
                return cell
            }
            multiImageCell.multiImageView.images = multiImageRow.images
        default:
            break
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Could it be because your resetting `multiImageView.images = []` the images on the prepareForReuse method?

Comment: You do not show code where you add the images to the cell.

Comment: @Claudio in the list of items I tried above, I have tried removing that line without success.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano it's hard to tell what it is, can you provide a reproducible example? Btw, I don't think you need to remake the constraints on the layoutSubviews

Comment: Add this line before returning  cell,   multiImageCell.multiImageView.images = multiImageRow.images

Comment: @NANNAV I already have that line inside my switch statement as the last line of code that runs

Comment: after return cell, that code won't execute , set breakpoint and check

Comment: @NANNAV i'm not sure what you're referring to, a breakpoint shows me that I'm definitely hitting the line that says `multiImageCell.multiImageView.images = multiImageRow.images` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a bug on the iOS 15 simulator on M1 processors. The code functions perfectly on a real device but not on a simulator. I intend to file a radar for this.